# JavaFX 2 Pane Dynamic Resizing

Tags: java, javafx-2, pane

I have a Pane within my interface. On that Pane I add Shape objects and drag them around.
I what to make my Pane bigger when one Shape reaches the visual bounds of the Pane. As a prototype,
I try to make it bigger whenever I click my mouse. The Pane is child (within) a ScrollPane. Here is my code:

```
    paneArea.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
            System.out.println(paneArea.getWidth()+" "+paneArea.getHeight());
            paneArea.resize(paneArea.getWidth() + 100, paneArea.getHeight() + 100);                
            System.out.println(paneArea.getWidth()+" "+paneArea.getHeight());
        }
    });
```

When I click twice I get the following result:

```
602.0 574.0
702.0 674.0
602.0 574.0
702.0 674.0
```

So the Pane basically resizes briefly and then returns to its original size.On the FXML, the max height and width are set to USE_PREF_SIZE as well as MAX_VALUE. I also tried to increase maxWidth/height before calling resize but made no difference. Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been using wrong method as well as fxml option. The way to do it was with setPrefSize method, and then set the max size at USE_PREF in fxml file.

Comment: My 2cents
I think you should also put min size as `USE_PREF` in fxml file.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong. Instead of using

```
paneArea.resize(paneArea.getWidth() + 100, paneArea.getHeight() + 100);
```

use

```
paneArea.setPrefWidth(paneArea.getWidth() + 100) ; 
paneArea.setPrefHeight(paneArea.getHeight)() + 100) ;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer although that problem is no longer relevant, so I cannot test this.